# Preg_match_all specific links

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have trying to search this in html code, how it can be repaired?

```
<a href="http://www.filman.cz/ex-machina-2015-3/" rel="bookmark">
```

(only that link)

I'm used this preg_match_all, but it seems to be badly written

```
preg_match_all("/<a href=\"([^\"]*)\"/", $links_area, $matches );
```

I don't know why, but it don't function. I think that somewhere will be badly writed "/" or "*" but I don't know exactly.
By the way, why is "Quality standards" on this site so hard? I have problem to post here everything.

Comment: If you want to match exactly that string with a regex, then this regex will do it: "/`<a href="http:\/\/www.filman.cz\/ex-machina-2015-3\/" rel="bookmark">/"`. [Test here](https://regex101.com/r/yN3rZ1/1)

Comment: Please update your question to show your expected output so I can properly edit and update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider utilizing **DOM** and **XPath** for this task, below is an example:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <a href="http://www.filman.cz/ex-machina-2015-3/" rel="bookmark">
     <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Visit Us On Facebook</a>
     <a href="https://www.paypal.com">Pay Now</a>
     <a href="http://www.filman.cz/ex-machina-2015-5/" rel="bookmark">
');

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xp->query('//a[@rel="bookmark"]') as $link) {
   $matches[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
}

print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.filman.cz/ex-machina-2015-3/
    [1] => http://www.filman.cz/ex-machina-2015-5/
)
```

**Note:** I'm not sure what you expect as output but this will help you to avoid using regex.

If you're simply trying to match the @href values that contains "filman.cz", you can simply use `contains()` OR `substring()` with the XPath query.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this regex. It match all elements starting with `<a` and select the inside of `href=""` attribute.*

```
<a(?:[^>])+href="(https?\:\/\/[^\"]+)\"(?:[^>])*>
```

Edit: I totally forgot about Xpath.. It's expressly designed for this kind of job, so use the answer from hwnd, that's the best option for parsing HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it could be less efficient but more accurate

```
/<a\s+href="(http(?:s)?:\/\/[\w\.\/-]+)".*?>/g
```

Explanation:

`<a\s+` -> tag 'a' + spaces

`href=\"` -> href til quotes

`(http(?:s)?` -> http or https

`: \/\/` -> literal ":" and "//"

`[\w\.\/-]+)` -> url characters

`".*?>` -> literal quotes and anything else until ">"

PHP code:

```
$re = "/<a\\s+href=\"(http(?:s)?:\\/\\/[\\w\\.\\/-]+)\".*?>/"; 
$str = "<a href=\"http://www.filman.cz/ex-machina-2015-3/\" rel=\"bookmark\">"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pK0dX3/4)